# selectively launch a function linked to href event depending on target file type?

Tags: javascript

I have a large number of href such as this one:

```
<a class="download " target="_self" href="../res/DOC140416-1.pdf" download="DOC140416-1.pdf
```

Others do not target pdf documents.

Is there a way to call a js function only for the href that target a pdf file?

I am looking for a js function that would load from index.html and that would be persitent throughout the "site" (it's for a hybrid app).

Thank you.

Comment: do you type all of the links manually or are they generated by the server?

Comment: Theh links are generated automatically. They are for offline use though (in other words a program genrates a list of links to files present in the assets of the app) The links look like this: href="../res/DOC140416-1.pdf".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can select all the links pointing to PDF file and execute a JS function on click of those.

```
$('A[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function() {
    alert('here'); //Do whatever you want
    return false; //Returning false to skip link normal behavior
});
```

Comment: Simple, efficient, What else do we need :-)

Comment: I tried to implement (successfully) you line of code. The next part seems to be trickier from what I gather. I'd like to have this file opened by the PDF reader (if any on the mobile) but I have not found out how. Any pointer? Thanks!

Comment: You shall post a new question for this and add the link here as a comment.

Comment: Ok,,I Will. Thanks